# Given three integer points, find an equation of a circle passing two of them and the third is inside.

Tags: geometry, circles

Given three integer points $P_1, P_2, P_3$, can we draw a circle passing through $P_1$ and $P_2$ (i.e these points are on its border), with the third point being inside the circle? If so, what is the equation of this circle?

Comment: Anything you have tried?

Comment: I was looking for a point $P_i$ and the distance between this point and the other two are equal.
In this situation the answer is found(the center is this point), otherwise no solution!

Comment: Do these points have specific coordinates in your excercise, or can they be any points? Because there are an infinite amount of circles which fulfill the conditions you specified.

Comment: they can be any points. (assume $x_i$, $y_i$ between -100 and 100).

Comment: What if the three points are colinear?

Comment: this is the simplest case! sort the points (according to x or y ) then consider the first and the third to be in borders of the circle. the second point in this case will be inside.